# Making a Doctrine migration adhere to ContainerAwareInterface

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, database-migration

I have a Doctrine migration that looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace Application\Migrations;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\PushNotification;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Migrations\AbstractMigration;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareInterface;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\Schema;

/**
 * Auto-generated Migration: Please modify to your needs!
 */
class Version20180123103147 extends AbstractMigration implements ContainerAwareInterface
{
    private $container;

    public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container = null)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    /**
     * @param Schema $schema
     */
    public function up(Schema $schema)
    {
        $em = $this->container->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $tableName = $em->getClassMetadata('AppBundle:PushNotification')->getTableName();

        $this->abortIf($this->connection->getDatabasePlatform()->getName() != 'mysql', 'Migration can only be executed safely on \'mysql\'.');

        $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE '.$tableName.' ADD COLUMN   last_offset int(11) ');
        $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE '.$tableName.' ADD COLUMN   failure_count int(11) ');
        $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE '.$tableName.' ADD COLUMN   is_sent int(11) ');
        $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE '.$tableName.' ADD COLUMN   send_date datetime ');


    }

    /**
     * @param Schema $schema
     */
    public function down(Schema $schema)
    {

        $em = $this->container->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $tableName = $em->getClassMetadata('AppBundle:PushNotification')->getTableName();

        $this->abortIf($this->connection->getDatabasePlatform()->getName() != 'mysql', 'Migration can only be executed safely on \'mysql\'.');

        $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE '.$tableName.' DROP COLUMN   last_offset ');
        $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE '.$tableName.' DROP COLUMN   failure_count ');
        $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE '.$tableName.' DROP COLUMN   is_sent ');
        $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE '.$tableName.' DROP COLUMN   send_date ');

    }
}
```

... and when running migrations, I get an error stating `Declaration of Application\Migrations\Version20180123103147::setContainer() must be compatible with Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareInterface::setContainer(Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface $container = NULL)`

This error seems out of place since I copied the method signature directly from the interface in question.

**Is there an obvious bit of code that I'm missing here?**

Comment: The error is complaining about method signature, from what I see you haven't imported `ContainerInterface` thus the type mismatch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are trying to inject the `container` into another service, this is generally highly discouraged. Rather, you can inject the `EntityManagerInterface` and use that.

However, I do see this is a migration file. There are no reasons in your given code why this should be here, rather just hard-code the table name like this:

```
$this->addSql('ALTER TABLE push_notification ADD COLUMN  last_offset int(11)');
```

So a summary, the reason you are receiving that error, is because the migration is expecting an instance of the container to be passed to your migration, this, however, never occurs since you did not register the migration as a service.

`(sidenote: never register a migration as a service)`

Comment: Good points here. Wouldn't injecting the EntityManagerInterface also involve registering the migration as a service?

Comment: As explained in the summary, yes.

Comment: Ah -- i see what you mean. Thanks.

Comment: Feel free to mark question as 'solved' if that is all :)

Comment: You don't need to declare the migration as a service, as explained [here](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/index.html#container-aware-migrations)

Comment: @FlorentDestremau Correct, but seeing what he wants to do, it practically seen is not neccesary

Comment: Is there any way to inject any service without declaring it as public in the dependency container?

Comment: @FedericoJ.ÁlvarezValero depends, where do you want to use it and how?

Comment: @MattSmeets Hard to explain in a few lines. Basically I want to use migrations not only to keep data model synced using SQL queries, but also to sync Solr cores definitions, insert/update/delete data updating caches and triggering some events.

It would be nice to inject only those services (that are not public within the service container) into the migration class.

Comment: @MattSmeets While you probably taught to OP something actually more valuable than answering his initial question, your explanation of why it occurs is wrong, it is a method signature error, not a lack of injection (ie: not a runtime error). malarzm is right, the answer to OP question is a lack of import for ContainerInterface thus the mismatching method signature.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason of your error is just because you did not put in the use section

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
```

In fact it's not the same prototype as the interface without the use (Not referencing the same class for ContainerInterface)

Nevertheless this, the remarks from the previous answer are rigth also !